# Ionic + AngularJs - Controller can not get array returned by Services

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have this view code:

```
> <label class="item item-input item-select">    <i class="icon
> ion-android-map icon-color"></i>&nbsp;
>       <span class="input-label">Estado</span>
>       <select ng-model="meuEstado" required>
>         <option value="0">Selecione...</option>
>         <option ng-repeat="estado in listaEstados" value="{{ estado.idEstado }}">{{ estado.nmEstado }}&nbsp;-&nbsp;{{
> estado.ufEstado }}</option>
>       </select>    </label>
```

Below is my service:

```
var starter = angular.module('starter.services', []);

starter.factory('appFactory', ['$http', function($http) {

        listaEstados: function(local) {

            var resultado = null;

            var dataToSend = {
                type   : 'recuperarestados'
            };

            $http({
                url: 'http://....',
                method: 'POST',
                data: dataToSend
            }).success(function(response, status, headers, config) {
                return resultado = response;
            }).error(function(err, status, headers, config) {
                return resultado = null;      
            }); 
        }
    };
}]);
```

This is the json returned:

> [{ "idEstado" : "7", "ufEstado" : "DF", "nmEstado" : "Distrito
>   Federal"},{ "idEstado" : "9", "ufEstado" : "GO", "nmEstado" :
>   "Goiás"},{ "idEstado" : "11", "ufEstado" : "MG", "nmEstado" : "Minas
>   Gerais"},{ "idEstado" : "19", "ufEstado" : "RJ", "nmEstado" : "Rio de
>   Janeiro"},{ "idEstado" : "23", "ufEstado" : "RS", "nmEstado" : "Rio
>   Grande do Sul"},{ "idEstado" : "26", "ufEstado" : "SP", "nmEstado" :
>   "São Paulo"}]

And here is part of my controller:

```
starter.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$state', '$ionicHistory', '$ionicLoading', '$timeout', 'appFactory', 
    function($scope, $location, $state, $ionicHistory, $ionicLoading, $timeout, appFactory) {

    $scope.meuEstado = "0"
    $scope.listaEstados = [];

    $ionicLoading.show({
        templateUrl:"templates/spinner.html",
        animation: 'fade-in',
        showBackdrop: true,
        maxWidth: 200,
        showDelay: 0
    });

    $scope.listaEstados = appFactory.listaEstados(local);

    //Define o tempo para remover o loader, 
    $timeout(function () {
        $ionicLoading.hide();
    }, 2000);
}]);
```

My problem is that my service can get the data from my back-end, but I can´t get this data from my controller, to load my $scope.listaEstados on the view also.

I notice in some posts here in Stackoverflow that I need to use "$scope.$apply", but I have already tried that without success.

Can someone please tell me what kind of change I need to do in my code, to get the data in the controller ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it with [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Service:

```
starter.factory('appFactory', ['$http','$q', function($http,$q) {


    listaEstados: function() {
        var deferred=$q.defer();
        var resultado = null;

        var dataToSend = {
            type   : 'recuperarestados'
        };

        $http({
            url: 'http://....',
            method: 'POST',
            data: dataToSend
        }).success(function(response, status, headers, config) {
            deferred.resolve(response);
        }).error(function(err, status, headers, config) {
            deferred.reject(response);    
        }); 
        return deferred.promise;
    }
};
}]);
```

In Controller:

```
starter.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$state', '$ionicHistory', '$ionicLoading', '$timeout', 'appFactory', 
function($scope, $location, $state, $ionicHistory, $ionicLoading, $timeout, appFactory) {

$scope.meuEstado = "0"
$scope.listaEstados = [];

$ionicLoading.show({
    templateUrl:"templates/spinner.html",
    animation: 'fade-in',
    showBackdrop: true,
    maxWidth: 200,
    showDelay: 0
});

appFactory.listaEstados().then(function(success){
     $scope.listaEstados=success;
},function(error){
     //Something to handle error
})

//Define o tempo para remover o loader, 
$timeout(function () {
    $ionicLoading.hide();
}, 2000);
```

}]);